# Proportional layout for iPhones (from 5 to 6 Plus) with Size Classes

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, size-classes

I have passed through a number of tutorials about Size Classes but still I cannot figure out one thing.

iPhone 5, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus have absolutely the same screen aspect ratios, so I want them to use the same content layout. By saying the same I mean proportional to width and height of the screen.

But! I cannot find a way to make it proportional for all iPhones!

There are just a few constraints that truly support proportions: "Aspect Ratio", "Same Width" + "Multiplier", "Same Height" + "Multiplier"

Constrains, such as Leading Edges, Horizontal Center In Container, all Pin constraints operate with absolute values in logical points, and all iPhones' screens have different sizes in logical points; thereby I cannot achieve the same picture on all iPhones.

### Update

I'm adding an image to explain what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: if you don't use width constraints with equals relation and high priority you shouldnt have a problem.

Comment: Let's say I need to place a view with Top space to container equal to 10 for iPhone 5. For iPhone 6 Plus this space should be proportionally bigger, because the height is bigger (in logical points)

Comment: I've defined a proportional constraint by specifying multiplier on vertical spacing, see this image: http://i.imgur.com/7fZTNey.png and let me know if that's what you mean

Comment: Maybe you can change the constraints between `compact width / any height` and `compact width / regular height` size classes to get a similar result but what you want to achieve is not the default behaviour.

Comment: Multiplier won't take effect with constrain equal to zero, however for non-zero values it could make sense, but in this case I would need to specify different Multipliers for iPhone 5, 6 and 6 Plus. And I doubt that it's even possible with Size Classes

Comment: @Jkmn are you saying that now we should have separate designs for iPhone 5 and for 6 family? I thought that making them proportional would be much easier and would require much less efforts from developers and designers

Comment: what's the point of having a bigger screen if you are going to increase the blank spacing everywhere ?

Comment: @Jkmn I am tormented by the same question; that's exactly what is happening if you don't scale up your design proportionally. See this image http://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/reviews/3572846/iPhone_6_PLUS_preview_MG_1834.jpg

Comment: The way I see it, they could have either increase app icons, try to fit 5 icons in a row or increase horizontal spacing, they choose the third option. In most of their app, they kept the same spacing, and take the additional space to display more content.

Comment: I understand your point, if we have, let's say, a table view, the table view should fit more rows on iPhone 6 Plus than on iPhone 5. But I have a design that is very sensitive to positioning of controls, think of it as if I have an image on the background, and I want buttons to be placed at very specific areas above this image, which obviously scales up proportionally to fit bigger screens. That's what you cannot achieve with Size Classes. I've added an example image to the post by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make such poor use of bigger screen, you could simply not include launch file or launch  images for 4.7" and 5.5" devices and they will just use a scaled-up 4" layout.

But please don't do any of that. The screens might be the same aspect ratio, but they are not the same size and treating them that way makes for a bad user experience.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, simply not including launch images for new iPhones. The client is happy with how it looks on iPhone 6 Plus, so you cannot blame me at this point. The real drawback of this is that Apple won't add text "Optimized for iPhone 6 Plus" near the app icon on the App Store

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by testing the image against the screen height (or width) eg:

```
//iphone 5
if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 568.0 {
// your code here
}
```

iphone screen heights are as follows:

iphone 5  = 568.0

iPhone 6/6s/7 = 667.0

iphone 6/7 plus = 736.0

Answer (score -1):

**Check this [Sample Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_wq4FyWzrQVUUR6VzlCRzJtb3M) i have made for you.**

Suppose you have a button, then follow the steps i have mentioned below to make proportional height, width and position of the Button to the parent View.

1. Give your Button Aspect ratio.
2. Give width equal to the parent View's width.
3. Add Constraint Center Horizontally in container and Center
   Vertically in container.
4. Select Your Button and then go to size inspector and set the
   multiplier for the width (like 0.3 or 0.4 etc).
5. Then set the multiplier for "align center X to.." (if you want your
   button to be left of center then set multiplier below 1 like 0.8,
   0.7,0.5 etc And if you want your button to be in the right of the center then set the multiplier value bigger than 1 like 1.2 etc).
6. Set the multiplier value for "Align center y to.." as like in Step

Its all done.. Just run and check.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.